# Use redux to reduce http requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux, react-redux

I am working on react app with redux, I got one component that repeats through the whole app, component shows some data from the server, data is always the same, should I use a redux store to save data and reduce HTTP requests when component shows on some other page?

Comment: Can you show code or UI image ?

Comment: @Sescudero He just wants to know whether it is a good practice to save static data in store. I don't think any code or images would be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go ahead with the redux store. While doing so, you can also add checks, for when you think the data changes and you can load the data then.

If you are confident that your data is not going to change, add a check for the first time and load the data and save it in the redux store, then just use the data from store.

Add your checks in the `constructor()`.

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly answer that I need